# Python-replace tripple and 4 times double quotes with a double quote

Tags: python, replace

I have  String like this:

```
"""{\""College\""
```

Want to remove 3 and 2 times double quotes to only one time like this:

```
"{\"College\"
```

How can I do that , I tried replace() function but it removes all the quotes.Can someone help please I am new to Python

Tried `replace("\"\"","\"")` but not working

Comment: How'd you get that string in the first place? Can you prevent it from getting messed up so you don't need to solve this issue? Is this string encoded or escaped according to specific rules which can be simply reversed? What if there's a legitimate double-quote?

Comment: Have you tried the strip method?

Comment: A better string literal for two double quotes would be `'""'`

Answer (score 1):

## 1

the following code repeatedly replaces 2 " with 1 ".
It does do log(n) loops and is not as efficient as a single loop would be, but it is readable and the algorithm is obvious.

```
mystring = '"""{\""College\""'
while '""' in mystring:
    mystring = mystring.replace('""', '"')
print(mystring)
```

(timeit shows 430 ns per loop)

## 2

alternate more complicated + more efficient(for larger strings) oneliner:

```
print('"'.join((e for e in ('|'+mystring+'|').split('"') if e))[1:-1])
```

(timeit shows 945 ns per loop)

the '|' is used to pad the string to account for the edge case where there are " on the ends.

## 3

and finally a regex based solution (sometimes pretty slow in python)

```
import re
print(re.sub('"+', '"', mystring))
```

(timeit shows 1.28 µs per loop)

Comment: As `"+` matches any occurence of ***one or more*** double quote, don't you want to replace with one double quote? Else you're removing ***all*** double quotes?

Comment: @MatBailie you're right, thanks for pointing it out. I meant to replace with double quote, not a space.

Answer (score 0):

You could solve this with a simple regular expression [(Docs)](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html).

For instance the expression: `\"{2,3}` would match any double or triple quotes.